# Error: geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have the following dataset in R :

```
month =c("January","February","March","April","May","June",
                 "July",    "August" ,"September","October","November","December")
value = seq(1:12)
d = data.frame(month,value);d
ggplot(data = d ,aes(x = month,y=value))+geom_line()
```

But when I run it, R reports me an error message :

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group
aesthetic?
```

Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you meant `geom_col()` instead of `geom_line()` or geom_point.  Based o nthe data there is only one point when the x is 'month'

Comment: I need a line in each month.And to be connected with the points.Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

months <- c(
  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
)


value <- seq(1:12)
d <-
  data.frame(months, value) %>%
  # prevent lexicographical sorting
  mutate(months = months %>% factor(levels = months))
d
#>       months value
#> 1    January     1
#> 2   February     2
#> 3      March     3
#> 4      April     4
#> 5        May     5
#> 6       June     6
#> 7       July     7
#> 8     August     8
#> 9  September     9
#> 10   October    10
#> 11  November    11
#> 12  December    12
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = months, y = value, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = months, breaks = months)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: nice.very good. but I want to start from january

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. Please specify this in your question at the next time.